# Troubleshooting non-reporting xymon clients

Tags: linux, monitor

I'm not well versed with xymon troubleshooting and the guy that normally supports xymon is on leave.  So I need a pointer or two on where to look for the problem.

We have a xymon ver 4.3.26 server monitoring roughly 1400 systems normally quite well.  We patched about 200 systems last night and, after all said and done, about 34 of these systems are showing purple on the 'all non-green' page.

This has happened before and the xymon server will 'catch up' after a time.  However, 12 hours later, these 34 are still showing purple for all tests.

I've tried restarting the xymon services on the client and, when that didn't produce results, restarted services on the server - still to no effect.

I've found the logs under /var/logs/xymon; but, nothing in those look untoward.  Some entries about garbled messages from unrelated hosts that have apparently been going on forever so unrelated to this issue.

So, long  way to a short question: how do I find out why clients are not able to report?  Is there a way to test connectivity or some other logs that show connectivity issues?

Answer (score 2):

After much poking about, I finally found /var/lib/xymon/tmp/xymond.chk.

- service xymon stop
- cp xymond.chk xymond.chk.161222 && > xymond.chk
- service xymon start

All statuses reset.  Had to go back and re-disable some tests but everything's working again.  I have the feeling I took a small thermonuclear device to a fly; but, the fly's dead, so ...